# How do I move  a div with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a div with text on the center of the page. When I click on the div it should be moved anywhere on the page (for example: 100px above). How can I do it?

Comment: Read some docs on javascript 1st.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code? Have you looked at any tutorials?

Answer (score 4):

Retrieve the element by id then set the `onclick` `handler`.
Then you can set the `position` for the element as follows:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7q8U/)

```
var element = document.getElementById('myDivId');
element.onclick = function(){
   element.style.position = "absolute";
   element.style.left = '100px';
   element.style.top = '100px';
}​
```

Comment: Yea, why they downvote. It clearly works.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I would assume no explanation to the code. just a block and a fiddle. The user is clearly new and maybe some links to the docs for more reading would help... or at the least a brief summary of what your code does (line by line maybe)