# sticking a div to mouse cursor doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting the user's name by a prompt and want to stick the user's name under mouse cursor by a div that includes the name.but it doesn't work.my div doesn't wove under cursor.what's the problem of my codes?

```
<body>
    <div id="myDiv1"></div>
    <script>
        var n = window.prompt("Enter your name please", "");
        var t = document.getElementsById("myDiv1").offsetTop;
        var l = document.getElementsById("myDiv1").offsetLeft;

        function myPointer() {
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
                var x = e.pageX;
                var y = e.pageY;
                t = y;
                l = x;
            })
        }
        myPointer();
    </script>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ywxLyv77/

Comment: What's not working? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Do you see any errors in console? Where, in your code, are you actually moving the div? If the code presented is complete, then there is your problem. `t` and `l` are set to `x,y` but you don't change the offsets of the actual div.

Comment: @scrappedcola no errors its just not moving with my cursor.the div i mean

Comment: `getElementsById` should be `getElementById`. See console errors.

Comment: @MelodyHajian you don't have any code present that would move the div.

Comment: @isherwood still not working!

Comment: It was a general suggest--use the console to troubleshoot errors.

Comment: @scrappedcola i used offsets.so what should i do?!

Comment: please help me solve the problem instead of vote down me :(  im just trying to learn...

Comment: You aren't using the offset top though. `var l = document.getElementById("myDiv1").offsetLeft;` stores the current value of the offsetLeft in the variable `l`. It will not update the value of `document.getElementById("myDiv1").offsetLeft;` when you reassign the value of `l` to `x`. The programming lang doesn't work that way.

Comment: @scrappedcola alright so what should i do? i want that div move under my cursor via javascript.

Comment: this question probably is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122220/how-do-i-move-a-div-with-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the syntax is `getElementById` instead of `getElementsById`.

Also, it seems that you are trying to set `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` by reference. First, [`offsetLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetLeft) and [`offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetTop) are read-only. Second, changing a variable that has been set to a element's property will not change the value of the property itself.

I had success by setting a CSS definition directly, using [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style):

```js
var mydiv1=document.getElementById("myDiv1");    

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    mydiv1.style.top = y + 'px';
    mydiv1.style.left = x + 'px';
});
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/un4zz2hg/2/)

### Edit:

You can tweak the position of the `<div>` relative to the mouse position by adding to or subtracting from the `x` and `y` values. For example:

```
mydiv1.style.top = (y-15)+ 'px';
mydiv1.style.left = (x-8) + 'px';
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/un4zz2hg/3/)

Comment: wow it worked! how can i change the distance of cursor and the div a little ?